# Splitting up a text file into sets of n characters

Tags: python, list, format, slice

So I have a long text file with a bunch of numbers and I want to reformat this file so that every 12 characters are on their own line, the file is 4392 characters long. My strategy was to add the contents of the infile to a list and slice and append the first 12 characters to a new list then write it to an outfile using a while loop for the list slicing parameters. I am getting an error on `out.writelines(l)` :

```
TypeError: writelines() argument must be a sequence of strings.
```

Here is my code:

```
l = []
outl=[]
with open('r6.txt', 'r') as f, \
     open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
     outl.append(f)
     a = 0
     b = 11 
     while b <= 4392:
         l.append(outl[a:b])
         l.append('/n')
         out.writelines(l)
         a+=12
         b+=12
         l=[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vlad-ardelean is correct in saying you need to append `f.readlines()` to `outl` instead of the file `f`.

Also, you're using `writelines()` to write a single line each time, but `writelines()` is intended for writing out a list of strings to a file, not one item lists.  Perhaps a better way to approach the insertion of newline characters would be:

```
l = []
outl=[]
with open('r6.txt', 'r') as f, \
    open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
    # gets entire file as one string and removes line breaks
    outl = ''.join(f.readlines()).replace('\n','')
    l = [outl[each:each+12]+'\n' for each in xrange(0,len(outl),12)]
    out.writelines(l)
```

Sample input for r6:

```
abcdefeounv lernbtlttb
berolinervio
bnrtopimrtynprymnpobm,t
2497839085gh
b640h846j048nm5gh0m8-9
2g395gm4-59m46bn
2vb-9mb5-9046m-b946m-b946mb-96m-05n=570n;rlgbm'dfb
```

output:

```
abcdefeounv 
lernbtlttbbe
rolinerviobn
rtopimrtynpr
ymnpobm,t249
7839085ghb64
0h846j048nm5
gh0m8-92g395
gm4-59m46bn2
vb-9mb5-9046
m-b946m-b946
mb-96m-05n=5
70n;rlgbm'df
b
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kevin this is perfect. I like your strategy of dealing with the new line characters. Would you mind explaining your for loop? I have never seen it used like that.

Comment: The for loop is a list comprehension.  You can read up on them, they're not too complicated.  But the `outl[each:each+12]+'\n'` takes a 12 char slice of the original line and appends a newline, and the `for each in xrange(0,len(outl),12)` means it starts at 0, goes for the length of the string, and loops in increments of 12.  The list comprehension part `l = [ stuff ]` means that the output of the loop gets assigned to the list `l`.

Answer (score 1):

Well you're appending the file object to the list, and then you're taking slices of the list and writing them. Perhaps you forgot the file object reference among the strings.

Just use a `print outl` to get your answer. If you've got a file object among the items in the list, then you know :)

OR better yet:

```
l = []
outl=[]
with open('r6.txt', 'r') as f, \
     open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
     outl.extend(f.readlines())
     a = 0
     b = 11 
     while b <= 4392:
         l.append(outl[a:b])
         l.append('\n')
         out.writelines(l)
         a+=12
         b+=12
         l=[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hm, although other answers seem to be correct, I still think that the final solution can be, well, faster:

```
with open('r6.txt', 'r') as f, \
    open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
    # call anonymous lambda function returning f.read(12) until output is '', put output to part
    for part in iter(lambda: f.read(12), ''):
        # write this part and newline character
        out.write(part)
        out.write('\n')
```

Comment: This is a great approach, however it only formats the output correctly if the input file is one long line with no line breaks already in it.  The OP didn't state the format of the original file, but how would you handle the situation where he had an input file with several line breaks already in it?